# Mapping between 2 table

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I have 2 tables one is `feestructure` and second is `feedetails`

`feedetails` is having the `feestructure` table id as foreign key and one `amount` field

So my question is when I enter a duplicate foreign key in `feedetails` and any value in the `amount` field, then the number of duplicate ids corresponding `amount` sum should be calculate and that sum of `amount` should display in `amount` field in `feestructure` table.

I am using spring, hibernate and MySQL in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need store the total amount of `feedetails` of a `feestructure` when you can derive it from a simple `GROUP` query. However, in case you have a reason to so so, you can try using a `TRIGGER` to handle the insertion process in the `feedetails` table.

This link may help [Before insert trigger](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0260__Trigger/Beforeinserttrigger.htm)